# DVD does not work - no solution found yet

Tags: video, video-player

So I've been thru a lot of trouble already trying to get the DVD running. I installed all the latest versions of all libdvd files (including libdvdcss2), I checked my country code and tried with another one, which also did not help. A slight "success" was only when I tried to rip the DVD, then i heard the title music in a extremely bad not fluent quality.
VLC gives me no message, preinstalled video gives me error message saying "Unable to play the file DVD source is required to play the file, but is not installed."
I am using ubuntu 18.04
My device is an Acer Aspire F 15 (I am using the integrated DVD-Player)
Questionable DVD is "The Mentalist" Series 1

Comment: You might want to see this as reference: https://www.howtogeek.com/138969/why-watching-dvds-on-linux-is-illegal-in-the-usa/

Comment: @AryoAdhi Thank you, that's a really interesting Article. Tho I am actually not affected, I am in Europe, the country code is Europe too, and the CD was also purchased here. And actually libdvdcss2 is installed, but still it does not work.